# Raphael JS Selecting specific instance of a path/object/node

Tags: javascript, variables, raphael, selection

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dhREK/32/

With Raphael JS I'm creating a series of triangles using a for loop. After creating the triangles I want to be able to animate any one of them by selecting the raphael objects by index, something like:

```
tri[1]
```

or

```
tri.1
```

but I'm not sure of the right syntax. In any case, using

```
tri.animate({fill: '#ff0000'}, 400)
```

only animates the last triangle.

How can I specifically select the other nodes?

Thanks!

```
var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var coords = 'M 43 0 L 74 63 L 13 63 Z';

    if(i % 2) {
        coords = 'M 43 63 L 74 0 L 13 0 Z';                      
    }

    var tri = paper.path(coords).attr({
       'fill' : '#000',
        'stroke-width' : '0'
    });

    tri.transform('T'+i * 34+',0');
}


tri.animate({fill: '#ff0000'}, 400)
```

PS: I was able to get all of the children of my paper as jquery objects (as seen in the jsfiddle link), but using `animate()` on a jquery object does not allow me to animate the raphael properties... any comment on that would be much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `tri` into an array.

```
var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500),
    tri = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var coords = 'M 43 0 L 74 63 L 13 63 Z';

    if(i % 2) {
        coords = 'M 43 63 L 74 0 L 13 0 Z';                      
    }

    tri[i] = paper.path(coords).attr({
       'fill' : '#000',
        'stroke-width' : '0'
    });

    tri[i].transform('T'+i * 34+',0');
}


tri[1].animate({fill: '#ff0000'}, 400);
```

Comment: I strongly suggest implementing `Paper.set` instead of array in accordance with Dan Lees answer.

Comment: I also strongly recommend implementing `Paper.set` rather than an array.

Answer (score 4):

More appropriate for this situation would be an array-like [`Paper.set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set)

You can define it like this

```
var triangles = Paper.set();

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  // ....
  var tri = paper.path(coords) //

  triangles.push(tri);
}

triangles.animate(
  // ...
);
```

Comment: Once they are in the set, how would I select *individual* triangles by index?

Comment: @j-man86 Like a normal array, e.g. `triangles[1]`. The advantage is that it implements the [composite pattern](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-design-patterns-composite/), meaning you can use for example `Element.animate` on a whole set.